# Derby Embedded create tabel inorder run on any pc

Tags: java, derby

Hi below code form from my Derby embedded example...
when i run on my pc(developed)it run smoothly.
And then i export as jar file and run on another pc .it throws an exception table already exists.
How can i create table only once on any pc

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    final String driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    final String url="jdbc:derby:db/testdb";

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        //connection.createStatement().execute("create table channels(channel varchar(20),topic varchar(20))");
    //  connection.createStatement().execute("insert into channels (channel,topic) values('hbo','action')");
    //  System.out.println("saved");
        PreparedStatement preStmt=connection.prepareStatement("select * from channels");
        ResultSet set=null;
        set=preStmt.executeQuery();

        while(set.next()){


            System.out.print(set.getString(1));
            System.out.println(set.getString(2));

        }       

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Also how to configure same issue on hibernate.cfg.xml file...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the table already exists before you create it.

Use the DatabaseMetadata calls to examine the structure of the database after you connect to it.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check before every creation check it in DB metadata:

Methods looks like following:

```
ResultSet result = databaseMetaData.getTables(
    catalog, schemaPattern, tableNamePattern, types );
```

Abd you can use it as following:

```
ResultSet result = databaseMetaData.getTables(
    null, null, TABLE_NAME, null );
```